# Different ORDER BY direction for MySql query results

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I am trying to do some ordering on a mysql query that I can't figure out.

```
id | status | created_at
------------------------
 1 | open   | 1348778070
 2 | closed | 1348711241
 3 | open   | 1348839204
 4 | closed | 1348738073
 5 | banned | 1348238422
```

How do I order the above table so that the 'open' records are first, in ASC order; and then the non-open records are second in DESC order? In another word, have a dynamic second level ordering direction based on some condition?

I have tried a UNION of two SELECT queries with ordering within them, which doesn't work because UNION by default produces an unordered set of rows.

Also I've tried a pseudo column that subtracts the created_at timestamp from a large number, for the closed status records, so I can just ORDER BY ASC to get the result as per below...

```
SELECT table.*, (table.created_at) as tmp_order FROM table
  WHERE table.status = 'open'
UNION
  SELECT table.*, (999999999 - table.created_at) as tmp_order FROM table
WHERE table.status = 'closed'
ORDER BY tmp_order ASC
```

This works but I feel there has to be a better way. Ideally a solution would not include a random big number as above

Comment: Can you do `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY status ASC, created_at DESC` ? I haven't tried it but what does it give you?

Comment: Roger should be right, and also there is no need for a UNION here at all.  You can specify multiple ORDER BY parts.

Comment: Ok I didn't outline my problem correctly, there actually could be different entries in the status column, it's just that I want the `open` ones to be first. I've updated my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATED**

```
SELECT *
  FROM tmp_order
 ORDER BY FIELD(status, 'open') DESC, 
          CASE 
            WHEN status = 'open' 
              THEN created_at 
              ELSE (999999999 - created_at) 
          END
```

or

```
SELECT *
  FROM tmp_order
 ORDER BY FIELD(status, 'open') DESC, 
          CASE 
            WHEN status = 'open' 
              THEN created_at END,
          CASE 
            WHEN status <> 'open' 
              THEN created_at END DESC
```

Output:

```
| ID | STATUS | CREATED_AT |
----------------------------
|  1 |   open | 1348778070 |
|  3 |   open | 1348839204 |
|  4 | closed | 1348738073 |
|  2 | closed | 1348711241 |
|  5 | banned | 1348238422 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f128e/6)** demo.

Comment: This looks close, but I was trying to avoid having to introduce that random big number. Also there are other `status` column entries, but I want the `open` ones to come first, in ASC order, then the others after that in DESC order.

Comment: Also that SQLFiddle demo is awesome, I've updated it with another couple of entires that make it closer to what I need.

Comment: @Norto23 See updated answer. You can use `FIELD()` to make rows with `status = 'open'` go first and then everything else.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT id, status, 
if (status = 'open', created_at, 999999999 - created_at) as tmp_order 
FROM table 
ORDER BY status, tmp_order
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would solve it:

```
SELECT
  id, status, created_at
FROM
  yourtable
ORDER BY
  status DESC,
  CASE WHEN status='open'   THEN created_at END,
  CASE WHEN status='closed' THEN created_at END DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you can probably do it in one query, but the general solution, which works for any two different and unrelated. orderings is to use two unioned subqueries each with their own ordering;

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT *
  FROM table
  WHERE table.status = 'open'
  ORDER BY created_at DESC) x
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM table
  WHERE table.status = 'closed'
  ORDER BY created_at) y
```

Comment: #1221 - Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY..when run the exact query in phpmyadmin

Comment: This still wont work as the ordering when using a union is not guaranteed

Comment: @Norto23 This is a `UNION ALL` (not a `UNION`), so order *is* guaranteed.

Comment: You are correct, it seems weird that you have to wrap both selects in other selects though right. I +1'ed your answer as this avoids using the magic number as in the other answer.